# Shadow File Permissions

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod, etc, shadow

I have some issues with files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. Both of them are without permissions.

And I don't know how this happened or why. Basically I can't edit/remove these files or change permissions when I am logged as the root user. It ends with *Operation not permitted*. Eg. when I try:

```
root@server:/etc# chmod 600 passwd
chmod: changing permissions of ‘passwd’: Operation not permitted
```

Whats the fix???????

Comment: can you provide result of `ls -l /etc/passwd /etc/shadow`? Because it seems strange to change permissions on these 2 files

Comment: even though you are "root" user you need to use `sudo`. I do agree with @damadam that it seems strange you need to chmod them, and would recommend caution.

Comment: @Smurfz87 - based on the prompt, he *is* root, so sudo is unnecessary. However, why is the OP changing permission of /etc/password to 600 (should be 644)? Are any other files affected; seems strange that only the aforementioned files have these permissions anomalies.

Comment: The filesystem containing `/etc` is probably mounted read-only.